# Symfony - Gitlab CI/CD with Deployer

Tags: symfony, gitlab-ci, php-deployer

I'm trying to set up `Gitlab CI/CD` on my `Symfony` project using [Deployer](https://deployer.org/) but i'm not able to do it.
When deployment is executed on my pipeline, i have an `Operation timed out error` which mean that my config is wrong.

**My gitlab-ci.yml :**

```
image: php:7.4-cli-alpine

stages:
  - deploy

before_script:
  - apk add --update git openssh-client
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - curl --show-error --silent https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
    - php composer.phar install -d app/
    - app/vendor/bin/dep deploy dev -vvv
  environment:
    name: prod
```

**My hosts.yml inventory :**

```
dev-server.com:
  stage: dev
  hostname: XX.XXX.XX.X
  user: deployer
  branch: develop
  identityFile: ~/.ssh/gitlab
  deploy_path: /var/www/recruitment_back
  keep_releases: 1
```

**My Gitlab pipeline error:**

```
$ app/vendor/bin/dep deploy dev -vvv
✈︎ Deploying develop on XX.XXX.XX.X
• done on [dev-server.com]
➤ Executing task deploy:prepare
[dev-server.com] > export APP_ENV='prod'; echo $0
[dev-server.com] < ssh multiplexing initialization
[dev-server.com] < ssh: connect to host XX.XXX.XX.X port 22: Operation timed out
➤ Executing task deploy:failed
• done on [dev-server.com]
✔ Ok [0ms]
```

I've also added variable `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` in `Gitlab CI/CD` settings and also added my public ssh key in `authorized_keys` on my server.
The deployment working good when executed on my local machine.

What's wrong with my config ?

Comment: deployer needs `~/.ssh/gitlab` as defined in your hosts.yml but in your gitlab runner there's no such file.

add to your `before_script` section

```
- echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/gitlab
```

Comment: It's still not working...

Comment: The problem was on my AWS EC2 configuration. My EC2 access was restricted only by my IP address. Is it possible to accept gitlab ssh connection to my EC2 server ? (Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Solution :**

1. Generate a temporary ssh key for Gitlab CI and add `PRIVATE_KEY` in Gitlab
   variables [image: screenshot]
2. Generate ssh key on my AWS EC2 server and add the public ssh key in Gitlab to
   accept `git clone`operation executed by Deployer
3. Accept gitlab host connection on my AWS EC2 server by executing the command `ssh-keyscan -t rsa gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`
4. Make sure your AWS EC2 server accept ssh connection for gitlab runner. I've accepted all ip but is there a best solution ? For example restrict by gitlab IP ?

**My gitlab-ci.yml:**

```
image: php:7.4

stages:
  - deploy

before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$PRIVATE_KEY")
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

  - apt-get install -y curl git
  - curl -LO https://deployer.org/deployer.phar
  - mv deployer.phar /usr/local/bin/dep
  - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dep

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - dep deploy dev -vvv
  only:
    - develop
```

If there is a better solution. Please let me know.

Comment: Remember: The private key is readable to everyone who is allowed to read the gitlab logs. To use masked private key see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64710518/8398149