# Storing SSH Private Key in GitLab repository variables

Tags: ssh, gitlab

Using GitLab CI, I want to push production code to a remote webhost.

To connect with SSH, I am storing the key pair's private key in the variables of my GitLab repository. I've also copied the public key to the authorized keys of the server. This is (part of) my `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

```
image: ubuntu

before_script:
  # Setup SSH credentials and known host
  - which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
  - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS"
  - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

This method works, but I'm questioning the security of it. Is my private key safe this way? How else can I achieve the result that I'm looking for?

EDIT: I'm particularly questioning the security of this method in a production environment.

Answer (score 2):

The official example is in [gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/)

Its [`.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) uses a [custom environment variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#custom-environment-variables) `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`, as described in "[How to simplify your smart home configuration with GitLab CI/CD  / Preparing the server (and GitLab) for SSH access](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2018/08/02/using-the-gitlab-ci-slash-cd-for-smart-home-configuration-management/#preparing-the-server-and-gitlab-for-ssh-access)".

As long as that [variable is masked](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#mask-a-custom-variable), this should be secure enough.

---

[sneaky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8398149/sneaky) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64699458/storing-ssh-private-key-in-gitlab-repository-variables/64710518?noredirect=1#comment129147001_64710518) to create a pre-processing file:

> `cat id_rsa | base64 -w0` insert into `script-part` of your job in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:
>
> ```
> mkdir -p ~/.ssh && echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | \
>   base64 -d > ${SSH_KEY_FILE} && chmod 0600 ${SSH_KEY_FILE}
> ```

Comment: You can't mask a variable containing a private key if it contains line breaks though.

Comment: @Clockwork Indeed. Not without pre and post-processing, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54675024/6309.

Comment: Create pre-processing file: `cat id_rsa | base64 -w0`
insert into script-part of your job in  `.gitlab-ci.yml`:  
`mkdir -p ~/.ssh && echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 -d > ${SSH_KEY_FILE} && chmod 0600 ${SSH_KEY_FILE}`

Comment: @sneaky Thank you for this suggestion. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: That just goes to show how fragile masking is: Anyone who wants to dump the key to the log, will. It really only helps if you have some compulsively chatty app in your tool chain, which must tell you about all the secrets you feed it. But you can alsoe Base64 encode any regular secret to circumvent the masking. It's "cosmetic security", and you have to trust the people with access to your pipeline -- and their authentication mechanism.

Comment: @RickMoritz Do you mean as in [this article](https://www.ferdinandlist.de/blog/gitlab_cicd_env_var_masking_base64/)?

Comment: The article shows how to mask something that cannot be masked natively, by encoding it in base64. The purpose of masking itself is mostly cosmetic though. It's not really a security feature, as you could still write the actual private key to the log, if a tool misbehaves, or someone gains access to your pipeline. It only protects you from people who have access to the build logs, but not access to the pipeline itself. This can be achieved by restricting pipeline execution/secret access to trusted branches, but requires a lot of coordination to pull off.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to bypass this issue by encoding on origin the value and then decoding it on the fly.

On my Makefile:

`KEY=$(shell base64 -w 0 private-key-file)`

On .gitlab-ci.yml file:

`- echo $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY | base64 -d |tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -`

and then i call gitlab-runner

`gitlab-runner exec docker ${build_target} --env 'SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=${KEY}'`